# What kind of notation is this?

Tags: php, asp.net, regex, json

I've a string which looks like this:

```
[{
  text: "key 1",
  value: "value 1"
}, {
  text: "key 2",
  value: "value 2"
}, {
  text: "key 3",
  value: "value 3"
}]
```

I'm not sure what kind of notation this is, AFAIK this is generated by a ASP .NET backend. It looks a lot similar to JSON but calling json_decode() on this fails.

Can someone bring me some light on this kind of notation and provide me a efficient way to parse it into a key / value array with PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any way you can change the output? Quoting the key names seems to allow it to parse normally:

```
$test = '[{"text":"key 1","value":"value 1"},{"text":"key 2","value":"value 2"},{"text":"key 3","value":"value 3"}]';

var_dump(json_decode($test));
```

Comment: I guess I could str_replace the text: and value: and enclose them in double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

It is JSON-like, but apparently not exactly to the spec. The PHP [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) function only likes double quoted key names:

```
// the following strings are valid JavaScript but not valid JSON

// the name and value must be enclosed in double quotes
// single quotes are not valid 
$bad_json = "{ 'bar': 'baz' }";
json_decode($bad_json); // null

// the name must be enclosed in double quotes
$bad_json = '{ bar: "baz" }';
json_decode($bad_json); // null

// trailing commas are not allowed
$bad_json = '{ bar: "baz", }';
json_decode($bad_json); // null
```

Answer (score 2):

That sample is valid [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/), which is a superset of JSON.  There seem to be [at least 3 PHP libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Implementations_and_Bindings) for YAML.

If it is in fact YAML, you're better off using a real YAML library, than running it through a regex and throwing it at your JSON library.  YAML has support for other features (besides unquoted strings) which, if your ASP.NET backend uses, aren't going to survive the trip.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like javascript syntax (similar to JSON).  Regular expressions are the way to go for parsing it.  Strip the '[' and ']', then separate on the ','.  Then parse each object individually.

Comment: The problem rises when a string contains a comma.

Comment: Regular expressions can handle quoted strings containing commas.  I've done it quite a few times.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a custom format.  Replace the [{ and }] delimiters at the beginning and the end.  Then explode on "},{" and you get this:

```
text:"key 1",value:"value 1"
text:"key 2",value:"value 2"
text:"key 3",value:"value 3"
```

At that point you can iterate over each element in the array and use preg_match to extract your values.

Comment: Technically there's no reason a string couldn't contain a `},{` ... even if it is much less likely than a string containing a `,`

Comment: The reason I chose to explode on },{ is because , definitely appears in the sample output as a delimiter between values within a field block.  But yes I agree.

Answer (score 0):

It looks almost like a sort of array-style data container - text being the index and value being the value.

```
$string = ....;
$endArray = array()
$string = trim($string,'[]');
$startArray = preg_split('/{.+}/'); 
// Array of {text:"key 1",value:"value 1"}, this will also skip empty conainers
foreach( $startArray as $arrayItem ) {
  $tmpString = trim($arrayItem,'{}');  // $tmp = text:"key 1",value:"value 1"
  $tmpArray = explode(',',$tmpString); // $tmpArray = ('text: "key 1"', 'value: "value 1"')
 $endArray[substr($tmpArray[0],7,strlen($tmpArray[0])-1)] = substr($tmpArray[1],7,strlen($tmpArray[1])-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your JSON data accepted by `json_decode()`, you could use the following regular expression:

```
function json_replacer($match) {
  if ($match[0] == '"' || $match[0] == "'") {
    return $match;
  }
  else {
    return '"'.$match.'"';
  }
}

$json_re = <<<'END'
/ " (?: \\. | [^\\"] )* "     # double-quoted string, with escapes
| ' (?: \\. | [^\\'] )* '     # single-quoted string, with escapes
| \b [A-Za-z_] \w* (?=\s*:)   # A single word  followed by a colon
/x
END;

$json = preg_replace_callback($json_re, 'json_replacer', $json);
```

Because the matches will never overlap, a word followed by colon inside a string will never match.

---

I also found a comparison between different JSON implementations for PHP:

http://gggeek.altervista.org/sw/article_20061113.html

Answer (score -2):

I have never used it, but maybe give a look at [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode).

Comment: gosh, you're right. I think I shouldn't try to answer questions at this hour.