# Regex: retrieve currency in JSON string

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the Google calculator to retrieve converted prices, a sample output is this:

```
{lhs: "9000 Euros",rhs: "12 721.5 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}
```

Now I cannot use `json_decode` for this JSON string, I've tried it but it doesn't work, so I'm using regex to retrieve the converted price in the `rhs` field.

I need to make the regex to be able to parse the number, not the currency name at all, just the number, however I have  a problem with getting the price that includes a space in the field, my regex so far only gets `12`, I cannot get the full thing `12 721.5`.

```
/rhs\: "(\d+|\s+)/i
```

How can I do this without including the price name? Note the response may/may not include space in the converted price and also a period.

Comment: Why doesn't `json_decode()` work? What error do you get?

Comment: json_decode doesn't work because that's not json.

Comment: I just get `NULL` when I `json_decode` it.

Comment: It's not JSON, it's a Javascript expression. Easy to convert or use a custom tokenizer on. A few dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349608/what-kind-of-notation-is-this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to extract out the number part, then your regex could be:

```
 /[,{]\s*rhs\s*:\s*"([\d.\s]+)/
```

The `[...]` square brackets are the appropriate syntax for the alternatives here (any combination of decimals and spaces).

**Edit:** Missing decimals dot, and some more regex for verifying the "json" consistency.

Comment: also to mention: colon is not a special character in regex (thus doesn't need to be escaped) and neither digits nor whitespace is case sensitive, so you can lose the /i.

Comment: This will only capture `12 721` cause of the dot.

Comment: This doesn't work, I got this in the matches: `Array
(
    [0] => rhs: "12
    [1] => 12
)`

Comment: @lolwut: Works for me. You're utilizing it wrong then. Show your current code.

Comment: My code is this: `preg_match('/[,{]\s*rhs\s*:\s*"([\d.\s]+)/', $rawdata, $matches);` where `$rawdata` is the string. And I got the output of `$matches` in the above comment.

Comment: @lolwut: Then the `$rawdata` does not really contain a space character where you've shown. Might be a NBSP or null byte rather. Try `\pZ` in place of `\s` and add the regex `/u` flag.

Answer (score 1):

The [...] should capture the space and the `.` and terminating before the space and the currency.

```
/rhs: "([\d .]+)\s/
```

EDIT:
Adding php code which gets the data (in my environment)

```
$string = "{lhs: \"9000 Euros\",rhs: \"12 721.5 U.S. dollars\",error: \"\",icc: true}";

$pattern = '/rhs: "([\d .]+)\s/';
preg_match($pattern,$string,$matches);
print "<pre>"; var_dump($matches); print "</pre>";
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: I get no matches for this regex.

Comment: Added my code that gets the data, could it be that this is not the typical space but &nbsp; or some other weird character for space?

Answer (score 0):

This regex: `/rhs\: "(\d+|\s+)/i` says (one or more decimal digits) or (one or more spaces). It doesn't allow for any combination of spaces of decimal digits.

```
$json = '{lhs: "9000 Euros",rhs: "12 721.5 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}';

$matches = array();
preg_match('/"?rhs"?:\s*"((?:[\d ])*(?:\.\d+)?)/', $json, $matches);
$usd = floatval(str_replace(' ', '', $matches[1]));
echo $usd; // Outputs '12721.5'
```

This should work, and will continue to work if they ever make their JSON valid.

Comment: I get this: `Array
(
    [0] => rhs: "12
    [1] => 12
)`

Comment: Nope, I updated it when you edited, gave me the results above comment.

Comment: @lolwut, it outputs a float, not an array. Try refreshing again, make sure it has `echo $usd;`

Comment: @lolwut Which version of PHP are you using? You can see that this code works here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/G1diD8